# PHP tries to call function without any name

Tags: php, function, undefined, fatal-error

When running this PHP code:

```
// test value
$value = "123456-7890";

// remove blank spaces and explode
$value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
$value = explode('-', $value);

// check number of digits depending on format
if ((count($value) == 1 && strlen($value[0]) != 10) || (strlen($value[0]) != 6 || strlen($value[1]) != 4))
{
    echo "wrong number of digits!";
}
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  () in /Users/Rikard/Desktop/test.php on line 10
```

As far as I can tell the problem arises in this part: `strlen($value[0]) != 10` but I cannot see why it appears, any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure there is no `$` prepending one of the function names, like `$strlen`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You see this:

```
if ((count($value) == 1 && strlen($value[0]) != 10) || (strlen($value[0]) != 6 || strlen($value[1]) != 4))
```

PHP sees this (`•` means non-breaking space):

```
if ((count($value) == 1 && strlen($value[0]) != 10) ||•(strlen($value[0]) != 6 || strlen($value[1]) != 4))
```

It always happens to me when I innocently try to copy some code from Mac/Safari. BTW, I tried to "edit" your question, and copied code from there for further examination.

PHP interprets the non-breaking space as a valid function name, and tries to execute it:

```
•(strlen($value[0])
```

Comment: I'm curious, how did you see it?

Comment: I don't understand how this would explain the error `Call to undefined function ()`. Can you give more explanation?

Comment: @Jocelyn Ok I get it, the extra space in the error message. Because it's like he is calling `•(strlen($value[0]) != 6 || strlen($value[1]) != 4)`, where `•()` is the function

Comment: I think SO strips out the non-breaking space. I tried to use it in function names over on code-golf, and it broke the code. Copy/pasting the code wont have it in.

Comment: Thanks @biziclop and Mathieu, now I get it. It is interesting to remember that!

Comment: It might be interesting to create a php obfuscator which changes all function names to invisible characters :)

Comment: This happens for me when I write || in if statements some times (also on OS X), somehow the application I use (Coda 2) manages to add a invisible character to the code, but those times I get a syntax error so this time I didn't take a look at the code showing the invisible characters, thanks for noticing!